# c# encryption/progress bar - increase speed of encryption

Tags: c#, encryption

So I've created an encryption and decryption GUI which will allow me to encrypt or decrypt a file to a new file. In my GUI, I have a progress bar which will tell me how long before the process ends. When I encrypt a relatively small file, it encrypts it relatively quickly. However when I try to encrypt a 100 MB file, it's incredibly slow! I think the problem is in my encryptBG_DoWork method where I have the for loop; I think it's the way I coded it. The question is that can I run the process quicker or is this the correct way to run the progress bar along with my encryption method?

```
private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        statusLabel1.Text = "Encrypting...";
        encryptBG.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

private void encryptBG_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=100; i++)
        {
            encryptBG.ReportProgress(i);
            if (Rijndael.Checked == true)
            {
                ed.EncryptFile(filePath.Text, Destination.Text, "1");
            }
            else if (TripleDES.Checked == true)
            {
                ed.EncryptFile(filePath.Text, Destination.Text, "2");
            }              
        }
    }

private void encryptBG_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        statusLabel2.Text = "(" + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%)";
    }

private void encryptBG_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        statusLabel2.Text = "";
        statusLabel1.Text = "Encryption Completed!";
    }
```

My encryption and decryption methods are in another project here.

```
public void EncryptFile(string sInputFile, string sOutputFile, string alg)
    {
        try
        {
            PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(skey, IV);
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(sOutputFile, FileMode.Create);
            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(sInputFile, FileMode.Open);
            int data;

            if (alg == "1")
            {
                RijndaelManaged rdProvider = new RijndaelManaged();
                CryptoStream cs1 = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                                                    rdProvider.CreateEncryptor(pdb.GetBytes(32), pdb.GetBytes(16)),
                                                    CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    cs1.WriteByte((byte)data);
                cs1.Close();
            }
            else if (alg == "2")
            {
                TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
                CryptoStream cs2 = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                                                    tdProvider.CreateEncryptor(pdb.GetBytes(24), pdb.GetBytes(8)),
                                                    CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    cs2.WriteByte((byte)data);
                cs2.Close();
            }

            fsIn.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();

        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I am reading your code correctly, your are encrypting the same file 100 times...

Comment: How long does it take without reporting progress?

Comment: @L.B Oh, I see. That's why it's so fast encrypting a small file.

Comment: @empi I don't think it would make a difference, because I want to know when my encryption is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is that can I run the process quicker or is this the
>   correct way to run the progress bar along with my encryption method?

Your use of BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress() and ProgressBar is correct for what your doing, which is encrypting the same file 100 times and reporting progress on each iteration.

If your goal is to encrypt the file only **once** and report progress using the progress bar, you need a finer grained algorithm for encrypting the file. For example, spit the file into fixed size blocks. Use a loop to encrypt each block and report progress as `TotalBlocksEncrypted/TotalBlocks`.